# PyQt5 behavior of setParent to display QWidget without layout

Tags: python, pyqt5

There has been a small problem with a little project of mine using PyQt5. I tried to add a random QWidget (in this example a QPushbutton) to a custom QWidget. However, I don't understand the behavior of the "setParent" function. When I use it outside of the custom QWidget, the QPushButton is displayed. When I use it in a declared function of the custom Widget, the QPushButton is occluded and I have no chance of displaying it outside of adding a layout (which I don't want). Here an example of the source code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class customWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.addButton()

    def addButton(self):

        button = QPushButton('not_showing')
        button.setParent(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()

    button = QPushButton('showing')
    button.setParent(w)

    button.move(50,50)
    w.resize(600,600)
    w.move(1000,300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There is no change, when adding the parent during the initialization of the QPushButton.

Comment: Your example works, for that I created a customWidget object inside main, you could publish the code you tried where you use customWidget. A class that does not create an object is never invoked

Answer (score -1):

When the function addButton exits, the button is removed.

If you want to see the button, try this:

```
class customWidget(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.addButton()
    self.button = None

def addButton(self):
    if self.button is None:
       self.button = QPushButton('not_showing')
       self.button.setParent(self)
```

You do not have this problem in the main function because this function does not return until the application is stopped.

EDIT: The comment was right, but you also missed some arguments. This will work

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class customWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(customWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.addButton()

    def addButton(self):
        button = QPushButton('not_showing')
        button.setParent(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = customWidget()

    button = QPushButton('showing')
    button.setParent(w)

    button.move(50,50)
    w.resize(600,600)
    w.move(1000,300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is wrong. The button will not be removed, because it has a parent. There is no need to create an attribute for it. The OPs code works fine with `w = customWidget()` instead of `w = QWidget()`.

Comment: Thank you, your edit worked! I have to be more careful, when implementing my __init__ in the future.